# C/C++ use a switch case match all alphabet

Tags: c++, c

I have a long `if () ... else if () ... else if() ...`  code,similar to：

```cpp
int token;
if((token >= 'a' && token <= 'z') || (token >= 'A' && token <= 'Z'))
    // ...
else if (token == '\n')
    // ...
else if (token == '^')
    // ...
else if (token == '&')
    // ...
```

It has a lot of `'=='` and few scopes like `token >= 'a' && token <= 'Z'`,So I want to use `switch` to rewrite this `if else`，But using `case` to match all alphabet is cumbersome.I know it can be written as the following code:

```cpp
int token;
switch (token) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
    case 'e':
    case 'f':
    case 'g':
    case 'h':
    case 'i':
    case 'j':
    case 'k':
    case 'l':
    case 'm':
    case 'n':
    case 'o':
    case 'p':
    case 'q':
    case 'r':
    case 's':
    case 't':
    case 'u':
    case 'v':
    case 'w':
    case 'x':
    case 'y':
    case 'z':
        // ...
        break;

}
```

But I think this is not concise, so I want to ask if there is a more concise way to use a `case` to match `a-z` and `A-Z`

Comment: A switch is really the wrong tool for doing ranges ... Also, there's `std::isalpha`,

Comment: What you wrote first is more concise.

Comment: GCC has it as its extension. [Case Ranges (Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html)

Comment: Instead of `(token >= 'a' && token <= 'z') || (token >= 'A' && token <= 'Z')`, why not `isalpha(token)`?

Comment: What do you want to do in each `case`?  If we know this we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: And guessing by the variable `token`, you're doing some kind of parser or lexical recognizer? Then why not add a simple `if` for recognizing "names", and else use a `switch` for other special symbols? That's usually what I do.

Comment: You can use a 256 byte lookup table (or 128 byte for 7-bit ASCII) to map each character to an action, and then `switch` on the action. All of the upper and lower case letters would have the same action. Operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%` might also have the same action.

Comment: @Ne C First of all describe how you want to classify characters.

Comment: A weakness/strength to `isalpha()` is that it is _locale_ sensitive.  Depends on coding goals if it is _better_ or not.

Comment: A side note on `token >= 'a' && token <= 'z'`: It's very unusual these days, but there's no guarantee that the letters are stored in ascending order. Or any sane order, for that matter. Best to use the collection of `is...` library functions to be absolutely certain there are no boobytraps coming your way.

Comment: As you can imagine, this is part of an interpreter, I decided to use if with switch instead of just if or switch. @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `case` in `switch` for dedicated chars and `default:` label for ranges:

```
switch (token) {
case '\n':
  // ...
  break;
case '&':
  // ...
  break;
case '^':
  // ...
  break;
default:
  if (std::isalpha(token)) {
    // ...
  }
  break;
}
```

Or a bit unusual

```
if (std::isalpha(token)) {
  // ...
} else switch (token) {
case '\n':
  // ...
  break;
case '&':
  // ...
  break;
case '^':
  // ...
  break;
}
```

Comment: Nice. I like the switch for out of range characters.

Answer (score 6):

Use a table to simplify the `switch()`.  [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75567462/c-c-use-a-switch-case-match-all-alphabet/75567746#comment133322086_75567462)

```
  // Table look-up of character to switch index.
  static const unsigned char type[UCHAR_MAX + 1u] = { //
      ['A'] = 1, ['B'] = 1, ['C'] = 1, ['D'] = 1,['E'] = 1, //
      ['F'] = 1, ['G'] = 1, ['H'] = 1, ['I'] = 1,['J'] = 1, //
      ['K'] = 1, ['L'] = 1, ['M'] = 1, ['N'] = 1,['O'] = 1, //
      ['P'] = 1, ['Q'] = 1, ['R'] = 1, ['S'] = 1,['T'] = 1, //
      ['U'] = 1, ['V'] = 1, ['W'] = 1, ['X'] = 1,['Y'] = 1, //
      ['Z'] = 1, //
      ['a'] = 1, ['b'] = 1, ['c'] = 1, ['d'] = 1,['e'] = 1, //
      ['f'] = 1, ['g'] = 1, ['h'] = 1, ['i'] = 1,['j'] = 1, //
      ['k'] = 1, ['l'] = 1, ['m'] = 1, ['n'] = 1,['o'] = 1, //
      ['p'] = 1, ['q'] = 1, ['r'] = 1, ['s'] = 1,['t'] = 1, //
      ['u'] = 1, ['v'] = 1, ['w'] = 1, ['x'] = 1,['y'] = 1, //
      ['z'] = 1, //
      ['\n'] = 2, //
      ['^'] = 3, //
      ['&'] = 4, //
      // Other elements are 0 since they are not explicitly initialized.
      };

  unsigned char token;
  switch (type[token]) {
    case 1: ...  break; // letters
    case 2: ...  break; // \n
    case 3: ...  break; // ^
    case 4: ...  break; // &
    default: // None of the above.
  }
```

This somewhat replicates `is...()` routines, but does not have a *locale* variance<sup>*1</sup> and 2) can be customized to your parsing needs.

Better to use named constants/`enum` than 1,2,3,4...

---

**Speed**

I suspect OP is using this code for tokenizing and belongs to the [3%](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/94903) of the time micro-optimizations are worth it.

---

<sup>*1</sup>  **Advanced**: Many `is...()` functions have some *locale* dependence.   Example: "In the "C" **locale**, `isalpha` returns true only for the characters for which `isupper` or `islower` is true." C17dr § 7.4.1.2 2
This mostly affects characters that are non-ASCII (outside the 0-127) range.  When tokenizing for a specific protocol, keep in mind that `is...()` function have *locale* variations.

Comment: An alternative to an `enum` is to map each class to a canonical representative: `['A'] = 'A', ['B'] = 'A', ['C'] = 'A',… ['Z'] = 'A',… ['\n'] = '\n',…` and `case 'A' : … case '\n': …`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, that approach lends itself to added clarity.  I suspect it makes for a more complex `switch()` code.   Later on, OP could use the 0, 1, 2, 3 , ... approach for a function table look-up.

Comment: Please, indicate that this is a fun answer and that people should not actually do that. Not everybody might get that...

Comment: @NeitherNor: Why do you think people should not actually do that? Mapping to a class and switching on the class is a reasonable solution.

Comment: @NeitherNor Depending on coding goal, this is a very good way to do it.  It is fast and highly portable.  For learner exercises, yes, `isapha()` is OK, but that has _locale_ issues.  What is best really depends on many other criteria not posted by OP.

Comment: @NeitherNor And what is wrong about it? I find it brilliant, to say the least.

Comment: @NeitherNor This is a very well written and serious answer. Please elaborate on your comment, or admit you were trolling us.

Comment: Code like this is hard to read and maintain. We might get talking if this is really about a rare case of micro-optimization (this was edited in after my answer), but nothing like this was indicated in the original question. So, the original version of the answer, without any "micro-opt" remark, was confusing at best.

Comment: @NeitherNor: Re “Code like this is hard to read and maintain”: No, it is not. This code is straightforward and easily understood and maintained. At most it needs a comment introducing the fact it maps to a class and dispatches based on the class.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If you consider scrolling through 256-element lookup table littered source code easy to read and maintain, we clearly have different standards. The whole thing might be acceptable in highly optimized code, _after_ it was shown to be a bottleneck and with some data actually proving that this is faster. There, one might also elaborate on why one cannot assume that A-Z are in sequence but, at the same time, assume that \n is used for a line break...

Comment: @NeitherNor: What is “scrolling through 256-element lookup table”? You do not have to “scroll through” the table to understand its function. As I mentioned, a simple comment will introduce this code, and any moderately education software engineer will understand it easily. And `\n` is defined to be a new-line character by the C standard. I would grade this code as close to trivial.

Comment: I liked your table driven approach. Since I've used similar approaches in the past, it was perfectly clear to me. So, I don't know why you got all the brouhaha over it. In my answer,  I used your code as the starting point to show some code I used in a real situation that is, perhaps, even more obscure to a less advanced programmer.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask if there is a more concise way to use a case to match
> a-z and A-Z.

Yes, there is.

```
int token;
if((token >= 'a' && token <= 'z') || (token >= 'A' && token <= 'Z'))
    // ...
```

can be simplified to just:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int token;
if(isalpha((unsigned char)token))
    // ...
```

> `isalpha()`
> checks for an alphabetic character.
> The value returned is nonzero if the character c falls into the
> tested class, and zero if not.

For the rest of the symbols, use either the — preferably — `switch()` statement, or the `if/else` ladder. The functions declared in [`ctype.h`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/ctype.h.0p.html) could help simplify things more.

As commented by @Mike, GCC provides a useful extension:
[Case Ranges (Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html).

Also see @Toby's answer here to see the [discrepancy between the two solutions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/280416/265278).

Comment: The two are functionally identical _if_ we can assume a character set where a-z are represented by contiguous integers. Fortunately, using `isalpha` (or `std::isalpha` if this is C++) does not require us to make this assumption.

Comment: @Chris, [Almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75567462/c-c-use-a-switch-case-match-all-alphabet#comment133322225_75567462) identical.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask if there is a more concise way to use a case to match
> a-z and A-Z

GCC has an extension:

```
void foo(char x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case 'a' ... 'z':
            printf("Lower case letter\n");
            break;
        case 'A' ... 'Z':
            printf("Upper case letter\n");
            break;
        case '0' ... '9':
            printf("Digit\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Something else\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

But of course, it will not compile using non-GCC family compilers.

Comment: Given all the crap they added in C2x, I wonder why they did not standardize this goodie?

Comment: @chqrlie I took 40y to spot that computers are using the binary system. So maybe in C55 they will add it.  They are like God. He also did not consult 10 Commandments.

Comment: I tried this extension, it's a nice feature, but I'm trying to develop this on msvc, hope it gets added to the standard sooner

Comment: @NeC `abandon all hope, ye who enter here`

Comment: @0___________: my favorite comment: https://github.com/bobbae/gosling-emacs/blob/master/display.c

Answer (score 1):

I like chux's approach of using a lookup table. In the source below, this is `swchux`.

It generates:

```
movzbl %dil,%edi
movzbl 0(%rdi),%eax
```

And, then 4-5 of:

```
cmp $x,%al
jxx ...
```

---

This is really fast with a limited number of `case` statements.

But, with a larger number of `case` statements, the `cmp/jxx` entries take up a significant amount of time.

I had a situation where there was a `switch/case` block with a hundred or so entries. So, this didn't scale.

By using a computed goto (using `&&label`), we can reduce this to (in `swfix1`):

```
movzbl %dil,%edi
movzbl 0(%rdi),%eax
jmp *tbl(,%rax,8)
```

For the use case I had, using the computed goto instead of the `switch` improved overall performance by 30%.

With some `cpp` macros, we can make the syntax similar to a `switch/case` block.

---

In the above examples, we're using an `unsigned char` lookup. If we use a direct label table, we can reduce this by one instruction (in `swfix2`):

```
movzbl %dil,%edi
jmpq   *0x0(,%rdi,8)
```

This eliminates one asm instruction at the expense of the lookup table using 8 bytes / entry (vs. 1 byte for the above).

---

Here is the `.c` source code for the above examples.

Note that here I just used the `DOIT` macro as a placeholder for the actual code in the `case`. In real code, each `case` would have its own/different code.

```
#include <limits.h>

int state;

#define DOIT(val_) \
    state = 256 + val_

static const unsigned char type[UCHAR_MAX + 1u] = { //
    ['A'] = 1,['B'] = 1,['C'] = 1,['D'] = 1,['E'] = 1,  //
    ['F'] = 1,['G'] = 1,['H'] = 1,['I'] = 1,['J'] = 1,  //
    ['K'] = 1,['L'] = 1,['M'] = 1,['N'] = 1,['O'] = 1,  //
    ['P'] = 1,['Q'] = 1,['R'] = 1,['S'] = 1,['T'] = 1,  //
    ['U'] = 1,['V'] = 1,['W'] = 1,['X'] = 1,['Y'] = 1,  //
    ['Z'] = 1,                      //
    ['a'] = 1,['b'] = 1,['c'] = 1,['d'] = 1,['e'] = 1,  //
    ['f'] = 1,['g'] = 1,['h'] = 1,['i'] = 1,['j'] = 1,  //
    ['k'] = 1,['l'] = 1,['m'] = 1,['n'] = 1,['o'] = 1,  //
    ['p'] = 1,['q'] = 1,['r'] = 1,['s'] = 1,['t'] = 1,  //
    ['u'] = 1,['v'] = 1,['w'] = 1,['x'] = 1,['y'] = 1,  //
    ['z'] = 1,                      //
    ['\n'] = 2,                     //
    ['^'] = 3,                      //
    ['&'] = 4,                      //
    // Other elements are 0 since they are not explicitly initialized.
};

void
swchux(unsigned char token)
{

    switch (type[token]) {
    case 1:
        DOIT(1);
        break;                          // letters
    case 2:
        DOIT(2);
        break;                          // \n
    case 3:
        DOIT(3);
        break;                          // ^
    case 4:
        DOIT(4);
        break;                          // &
    default:                            // None of the above.
        DOIT(0);
        break;
    }
}

#define CASE(idx_) \
    CASE_##idx_
#define V(case_) \
    &&CASE(case_)

#undef SWITCH
#define SWITCH(idx_) \
    goto *swvec[idx_]

void
swfix1(unsigned char token)
{

    static void *swvec[5] = {
        V(0),
        V(1),
        V(2),
        V(3),
        V(4),
    };

    do {
        SWITCH(type[token]);

        CASE(1):
            DOIT(1);
            break;                          // letters
        CASE(2):
            DOIT(2);
            break;                          // \n
        CASE(3):
            DOIT(3);
            break;                          // ^
        CASE(4):
            DOIT(4);
            break;                          // &
        CASE(0):
            DOIT(0);
            break;
    } while (0);
}

#undef SWITCH
#define SWITCH(idx_) \
    goto *swvec[idx_]

void
swfix2(unsigned char token)
{

    static const void *swvec[UCHAR_MAX + 1u] = {    //
        ['A'] = V(1),['B'] = V(1),['C'] = V(1),['D'] = V(1),['E'] = V(1),   //
        ['F'] = V(1),['G'] = V(1),['H'] = V(1),['I'] = V(1),['J'] = V(1),   //
        ['K'] = V(1),['L'] = V(1),['M'] = V(1),['N'] = V(1),['O'] = V(1),   //
        ['P'] = V(1),['Q'] = V(1),['R'] = V(1),['S'] = V(1),['T'] = V(1),   //
        ['U'] = V(1),['V'] = V(1),['W'] = V(1),['X'] = V(1),['Y'] = V(1),   //
        ['Z'] = V(1),                       //
        ['a'] = V(1),['b'] = V(1),['c'] = V(1),['d'] = V(1),['e'] = V(1),   //
        ['f'] = V(1),['g'] = V(1),['h'] = V(1),['i'] = V(1),['j'] = V(1),   //
        ['k'] = V(1),['l'] = V(1),['m'] = V(1),['n'] = V(1),['o'] = V(1),   //
        ['p'] = V(1),['q'] = V(1),['r'] = V(1),['s'] = V(1),['t'] = V(1),   //
        ['u'] = V(1),['v'] = V(1),['w'] = V(1),['x'] = V(1),['y'] = V(1),   //
        ['z'] = V(1),                       //
        ['\n'] = V(2),                      //
        ['^'] = V(3),                       //
        ['&'] = V(4),                       //
        // Other elements are 0 since they are not explicitly initialized.
    };

    do {
        SWITCH(token);

        CASE(1):
            DOIT(1);
            break;                          // letters
        CASE(2):
            DOIT(2);
            break;                          // \n
        CASE(3):
            DOIT(3);
            break;                          // ^
        CASE(4):
            DOIT(4);
            break;                          // &
        CASE(0):
            DOIT(0);
            break;
    } while (0);
}
```

---

Here is the source built with `-S`:

```
    .file   "all.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  swchux
    .type   swchux, @function
swchux:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movzbl  %dil, %edi
    movzbl  type(%rdi), %eax
    cmpb    $2, %al
    je  .L2
    jbe .L10
    cmpb    $3, %al
    je  .L6
    cmpb    $4, %al
    jne .L5
    movl    $260, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L10:
    cmpb    $1, %al
    jne .L5
    movl    $257, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
    movl    $258, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L5:
    movl    $256, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L6:
    movl    $259, state(%rip)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   swchux, .-swchux
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  swfix1
    .type   swfix1, @function
swfix1:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movzbl  %dil, %edi
    movzbl  type(%rdi), %eax
    jmp *swvec.1969(,%rax,8)
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L17:
    movl    $256, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L16:
    movl    $260, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L15:
    movl    $259, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L14:
    movl    $258, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L12:
    movl    $257, state(%rip)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   swfix1, .-swfix1
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  swfix2
    .type   swfix2, @function
swfix2:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    movzbl  %dil, %edi
    jmp *swvec.1979(,%rdi,8)
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L23:
    movl    $260, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L22:
    movl    $259, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L21:
    movl    $258, state(%rip)
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L19:
    movl    $257, state(%rip)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   swfix2, .-swfix2
    .section    .rodata
    .align 32
    .type   swvec.1979, @object
    .size   swvec.1979, 2048
swvec.1979:
    .zero   80
    .quad   .L21
    .zero   216
    .quad   .L23
    .zero   208
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .zero   24
    .quad   .L22
    .zero   16
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .quad   .L19
    .zero   1064
    .align 32
    .type   swvec.1969, @object
    .size   swvec.1969, 40
swvec.1969:
    .quad   .L17
    .quad   .L12
    .quad   .L14
    .quad   .L15
    .quad   .L16
    .align 32
    .type   type, @object
    .size   type, 256
type:
    .zero   10
    .byte   2
    .zero   27
    .byte   4
    .zero   26
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .zero   3
    .byte   3
    .zero   2
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .zero   133
    .comm   state,4,4
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: With "with a hundred or so entries.", perhaps use the index into a function array instead of a `switch`.  Of course it depends on what the original `case`s were doing.